# Scope of Trigger coverage when trigger references other classes?

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

So for example I have a Trigger that references 3 classes. The trigger itself is at 100%, but all the 3 classes are only at 60%. Will the classes not being at the minimum cause the trigger to not be successfully moved into and used in production?

Answer (score 2):

If the overall coverage of apex in Prod is above 75% (including all classes and triggers), and your trigger is at least 1%, you should be fine.

So in your case, your trigger is 100% - great. The 3 classes can remain at 60%, as long as those classes combined with the rest of the classes and triggers provide > 75% coverage.

Note: You should always strive for 100%!

Comment: +1 but 100% coverage should be (nearly) impossible. A more realistic goal is 90%; the remaining 10% should account for untestable error handling, like dealing with row locks and other things you can't simulate.

Comment: There is a very small percentage of errors that can't be handled. Most of the error handling can be still tested. That's why I said 'strive'. If your can test your code 100%, then you should.